# Using rsync for specific files and directories

Tags: rsync

I am trying to find the optimum way to back up dotfiles, and I have devised a way to do it. I am using git with rsync to back up all the dotfiles. The rsync script looks like this right now:

```
rsync -avhP $HOME/.??* --exclude-from=$HOME/.dotBackup/exclusions.list $HOME/.dotBackup
```

However, I do not think that is the optimal way, and instead of excluding files using `exclude-from` arg, I want to do it the other way round, and have a list of specific directories and files I want to back up. And this is where things get a little murky. For example, I might want to back up some files in `~` and the directory of `~` looks like this:

```
~
|- Downloads (do not back up)
|- .bashrc (back up)
|- .config
     |- nvim (back up including subdirectories)
     |- code
          |- extensions (do not back up)
          |- preferences.json (back up)
```

How can I do such a thing using rsync?

Comment: Some info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using an rsync filter file, use it with option `--filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'` or simply `-F`.

Put the file `.rsync-filter` into your rsync source directory (your `$HOME`) with the following content:

```
# include .bashrc
+ /.bashrc

# include .config dir (parent of nvim and code)
+ /.config/

# exclude (overrides nvim include below)
- /.config/nvim/but_not_this_dir/

# include nvim dir and everything in this directory
+ /.config/nvim/***

# include code dir and preferences.json
+ /.config/code/
+ /.config/code/preferences.json

# exclude everything in the source dir
- *
```

Since we exclude everything in the source directory with `- *`, you need to add all the directories you want to include manually including their parent dirs up to the source dir. To include `foo/bar/`, but not `foo/abc/`, you need to add `+ /foo/` to override `- *` and `+ /foo/bar/`. Overrides to these includes need to be added before those includes.

Test your command using the dry-run option `-n` to see the output, add `-vv` to see which files/directories are shown/hidden by the filters.

Your modified command would be:

```
rsync -avFhp ~/ ~/.dotBackup
```

It makes sense to use a filter like this if you need a lot of overrides (sync this and that dir, but exclude this/foo and that/bar/baz). Use the `--files-from` option in [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/733613/332764) for simpler use cases.

Comment: Roaima's answer was simpler, but this one feels a lot more comprehensive, which is why it's chosen as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I might want to back up files in `~/.config/ABC/` except `~/.config/ABC/ex`
> How can I do such a thing using `rsync`?

- Include the files and directories that you want
- Exclude the files and directories that you don't want

So, assuming the command is run from `$HOME`, we have this:

```
rsync --dry-run -avP --exclude '/ex' .config/ABC/ ABCBackup
```

Or if you are talking about modifying your existing command that copies all dot files and directories underneath `$HOME`:

```
rsync --dry-run -avP --exclude '.config/ABC/ex/' --exclude '.dotbackup/' .??* .dotBackup
```

---

Working from the statement, "*I want to […] have a list of specific directories and files I want to back up*", this is much much easier.

Put the list of files into a file such as `$HOME/.to_backup`. Where you have complete directories to be included add those too - with a trailing slash. All paths can be relative to `$HOME`. Using your example tree, the file would include these entries:

```
.bashrc
.config/nvim/
.config/code/preferences.json
```

And then use this command (remove `--dry-run` once it's working as expected):

```
cd    # Start from $HOME so relative paths in the source file work correctly
rsync --dry-run --files-from .to_backup -arvP . .dotBackup/
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make it a bit more representative of my use case. Hope it helps.

Comment: One more thing: What if I change my example and want to back up the directory `.config/code` except `.config/code/extensions`?

Comment: @NibaronChakraborty in that scenario I'd go for a filter file